# inconsistent behaviour of interactive session and script in Python

Tags: python, import, interactive

When I run the script, I had this ImportError:

```
$ python ~/Dropbox/code/py/ZoteroFindOrphanedFiles.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zane/Dropbox/code/py/ZoteroFindOrphanedFiles.py", line 1, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 23, in <module>
    import datetime
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/datetime.py", line 20, in <module>
    import math as _math
  File "/home/zane/Dropbox/code/py/math.py", line 3, in <module>
    from nzmath.rational import Integer, Rational
ImportError: No module named nzmath.rational
```

But I don't have it when running the interactive session:

```
$ python
Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 23 2012, 23:14:44) 
[GCC 4.7.0 20120414 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>>
```

Why is that?

Comment: Its failing on the line "from nzmath.rational import Integer, Rational"

Comment: Can you try importing Integer from nzmath.rational on interactive session? After that compare sys.path from both sessions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
  import math as _math
File "/home/zane/Dropbox/code/py/math.py", line 3, in <module>
```

You have your own module called `math.py`, but this is the same as a standard Python module of the same name. This is not recommended.

The solution is to rename your `math.py` to something else, and don't forget to *delete* the `math.pyc` in the same directory (otherwise you'll still have the same problem).

Comment: right, it's a stupid mistake. I should have read the error message more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You have a local file
`/home/zane/Dropbox/code/py/math.py`
which is getting imported instead of the standard lib `math` module.

The solution is to rename your `/home/zane/Dropbox/code/py/math.py` to something else.

The problem occurs when you call a script in the `/home/zane/Dropbox/code/py` directory since this adds this directory to the beginning of `sys.path` and thus this directory gets searched first when Python tries to import modules.

Answer (score 0):

You have a file called `math.py` in the script's directory, and this shadows the stdlib `math` module. Rename the file.